# Jquery-ui droppable creating unwanted negative left position

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I've been struggling with this for a couple of days and I'm about to lose my temper. The plan is to drag an icon from a list, drop a clone of said item into a designated area (in cursor position), then a user can resize the clone as appropriate. The drag, clone, and resize work as planned. However the drop is causing me no end of problems. When dropping the item it moves massively to the left (using negative left positioning) and outside the div it's supposed to sit in. I've tried everything I can think of and can't solve this problem myself. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".droppable").droppable({
      accept: '.draggable',
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $clone = ui.helper.clone();
        if (!$clone.is('.inside-droppable')) {
          $(this).append($clone.addClass('inside-droppable').draggable({
            containment: '.droppable',
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            position: 'relative'
          }));

          $clone.resizable({
            aspectRatio: 'true',
            ghost: 'true',
            handles: 'ne, nw, se, sw',
          });
        }
      }
    });
    $(".draggable").draggable({
      helper: 'clone',
      revert: "invalid"
    });
  }); < /script>
```

```css
#content {
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 0;
  min-height: 0px;
  clear: both;
}
#form-window.scheme {
  width: 97%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 760px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#icon_menu {
  width: 45px;
  right: 381px;
  position: absolute;
}
#icon_menu li {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  position: absolute;
}
.draggable {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(127, 214, 236, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.droppable {
  position: absolute;
  width: 71%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="content">
  <div id="form-window" class="scheme">
    <ul id="icon_menu">
      <li class="draggable"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="droppable"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem eventually. Once I changed the positioning of the ul to relative everything worked fine. Why this was causing the drop to not position properly I don't know, however relative position did the trick.

```
#icon_menu {
width: 45px;
right: 381px;
position: relative;
}
```